# Unauthorised admin on Cloudant Local using nodejs-cloudant (nano)

Tags: node.js, couchdb, local, cloudant, couchdb-nano

I've been trying to get cloudant local going for a couple of hours. I've installed via docker as described [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/cloudant-developer/)

I can access the dashboard on `localhost:8080` with the default creds. And I can curl the DB when I supply same creds e.g. `curl -X PUT $HOST/database -u admin:pass`

The problem is, when I connect with the [nodejs-cloudant](https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant) module I always get 401 - Unauthorised errors, specifically:

`{ error: 'unauthorized',
  reason: 'one of _all_dbs, _admin, server_admin is required for this request',
  statusCode: 401 }`

It seems that the issue is that there is no user being returned when cloudant local connects. When I connect to my cloud based cloudant instance, the `reply.userCtx` is populated, however when connecting locally it is: `userCtx: { name: null, roles: [] } }`

The actual login seems to be working though as I've tested with incorrect creds.

This is where I am setting the credentials:

```js
    const credentials = {
      account: (stage === 'local') ? 'admin' : db.credentials.username,
      password: (stage === 'local') ? 'pass' : db.credentials.password,
      plugin: 'promises',
    }
    if (stage === 'local') {
      credentials.url = 'http://localhost:8080'
    }
    this.cloudant = cloudant(credentials)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply the url like this:

```
var url="http://admin:pass@localhost:8080";
this.cloudant = cloudant({ url: url, plugin: "promises"});
```

then it works fine.

The problem is when you say `account = 'admin'`, the library assumes a hostname of `admin.cloudant.com`. If you supply the full URL, then it is unambiguous and works perfectly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks heaps, working well! This means I don't have to also pass in the redundant account and password fields correct?